# Is there a word for surnames that originated from a profession?

Tags: single-word-requests

Surnames like *Cook* and *Smith* originally arose from the professions of those respective names. Is there a term for this type of surname?

Comment: you may also be interested in the theory of "nominative determinism" wherein it is proposed that an individual's surname may draw them towards an aptly named profession  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_determinism

Answer (score 4):

The term I'm seeing used is **occupational surname**:

- [Category:Occupational surnames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Occupational_surnames) (Wikipedia)
- [Occupations, occupational surnames and the development of society](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.0022-3840.1974.0801_99.x/full)
- [A Butcher by Any Other Name Is a... Carter: The Reliability and Stability of Occupational Surnames in King's Lynn c. 1400](https://kb.osu.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/1811/71232/1/ENARRATIO_Myers_vol4_pp1-15.pdf)
- [Office and Occupational Surnames in Spain](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1179/nam.1976.24.3.144?journalCode=ynam20)